# make list in list dynamic in python, problem?

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

i want to make a list by combining the results of n. but when the x values are different, it creates a new list. However, if the x value is the same, it will be in 1 list

My code is like this

```
muy = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
# will = []
for x in muy:
    for y in muy:
        if x != y:
            print(x, " ", y)
            m = np.subtract(x, y)
            n = sum(m)
            print(m)
            print(n)
```

the result is like this

```
[1, 2, 3]   [4, 5, 6]
[-3 -3 -3]
-9
[1, 2, 3]   [7, 8, 9]
[-6 -6 -6]
-18
[4, 5, 6]   [1, 2, 3]
[3 3 3]
9
[4, 5, 6]   [7, 8, 9]
[-3 -3 -3]
-9
[7, 8, 9]   [1, 2, 3]
[6 6 6]
18
[7, 8, 9]   [4, 5, 6]
[3 3 3]
9
```

the result what i want is like this:

```
[[-9,-18][9,-9][18,9]]
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
muy = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
will = []
for x in muy:
    temp = []
    for y in muy:
        if x != y:
            m = np.subtract(x, y)
            n = sum(m)
            temp.append(n)
    will.append(temp)
print(will)
```